# tooltip does not show date in the correct format

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

The tool tip does not show the date in the correct format in the line chart.( the image below). However the data was displayed in the correct format in the table below.

My code is listed here. Could anyone share some useful information to convert the integer to the year/month/day in the tooltip. Thanks,

Hank

```
def makeplotTDS(samplesTDS):
years=[ri["CollectionDate"] for ri in samplesTDS]
values=[ri["TdsValue"] for ri in samplesTDS]


sourcetds = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        year=years,
        value=values,

    )
)

hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips="""
         <div style="background: #FFFFFF;">
            <span style="font-size: 20px;">Year, TDS Value</span><br />
            <span style="font-size: 16px; color: black;">(@year, @value)</span>
        </div>
    """
```

)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create another variable in the data source that contains the date in string format.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure,show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource,HoverTool
from time import gmtime,strftime
from calendar import timegm

dates = [(2011,3,15),(2011,8,22),(2012, 7,17),(2012,11,13),(2013, 7,16),
        (2013,11,18),(2014,12, 1),(2015, 6, 8),(2015,12, 7)]
values = [1050,1250,1100,1700,1200,2650,1400,1050,1100]
years = [timegm(x+(0,0,0))*1000 for x in dates]

p = figure(plot_width = 600, plot_height=300, x_axis_type="datetime")
sourcetds = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        year  = years,
        value = values,
        syear = [strftime("%Y-%m-%d",gmtime(x/1000)) for x in years]
        # syear is the date in string format
    )
)

p.line(x='year', y='value', source = sourcetds)
p.circle(x='year', y='value', source = sourcetds)

hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips="""
         <div style="background: #FFFFFF;">
            <span style="font-size: 20px;">Year, TDS Value</span><br />
            <span style="font-size: 16px; color: black;">(@syear, @value)</span>
        </div>
    """)
p.add_tools(hover)
show(p)
```

The result is:
[image]